# PayPal Integration Android Sandbox redirect_uri error

Tags: android, paypal

I am integrating [Paypal Login](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/detailed/) with android Platform. But I am having an issue in authentication and authorization process. When I add all the required parameter and Call it, I get response code 200 on success.

But as a body of response i get the following:

```
 <HTML>
<BODY Onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<FORM NAME="Error page" METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/ph/error">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="error_code" VALUE="2005"/>
</FORM>
</BODY></HTML>
```

If i paste the Url given in **ACTION** on Web browser and check it i get the following:

```
Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request.
```

But when i was creating the Application i did get any redirect URI,and when application is created (approved from paypal) in application detail I have **Return URL** in which i paste the required URL but in vain .

Any one have any idea how to get the **redirect_uri** while creating application.

Comment: why down vote any reason ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503524/how-to-set-a-redirect-uri-for-login-with-paypal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the additional return URL (test) in the application details

Set LOG ON WITH PAYPAL to ON and then enter the return URL and the additional one (click on the link under that prompt) and then save

Comment: yes that`s what i have done already but thanx for your effort