# How to Set a Redirect URI For Login with PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to setup a `redirect_uri` so my app doesn't keep erroring with:

> Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request
>   does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the
>   request.

Where is this set? I'm using the online tool found here: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/ruby?success=true&env=sandbox. I've checked in the PayPal developer portal and can't find a redirect URI. Closest is a return URL (Where users will be redirected after test transactions) but setting that didn't remove the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently PayPal hosts two developer admin portals...

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps (change redirect URI)

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications (can't change redirect URI)

If you just browse to developer.paypal.com and login you go to the one that doesn't allow for redirect URIs. Someone at PayPal needs to start fixing the developer tools and updating the documentation.

**Note**: ensure that the URL contains some sort of trailing slashes also seems to have helped and changing this can apparently take 3 hours to propagate.

Comment: This would have taken me forever to figure out.

Comment: I have the same error and on both link I can only change the "return url"

Comment: I can confirm that it can take up to 3 hours to work. Had atleast 2 hour delay when testing mine.